# Setup is starting services; wim deployment is hanging on this

Tags: windows

I just imaged a laptop, it was working fine. When I applied the image (foolishly to the same laptop I took the image from) it won't boot any more. It hangs on "Setup is starting services". I pulled the setupact.log file and at the end it is filled with:

2013-10-11 13:32:15, Info                  PANTHR InitializeModule: Initializing ExecQueue->csLock;

It won't even boot into safe mode as it says it needs to complete installation first. I'd already generalized the image and booted into it before generalizing it again to image it. All the devices were working fine and it should be exactly the same. Can anyone point me to where I should be looking for clues. I don't have a long time to get this working (only about four hours).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted this now. Didn't realise that you could alt+tab to see error messages that had popped up and you can shift+f10 to get to a command prompt.

The issue came about because after I sysprepped it I had accidentally set the computer to reboot rather than shut down and I missed the POST screen to get the boot options. I quickly powered it off using the power button rather than having to sysrep it again and I though I'd caught it in time (I did all this the day before and had forgotten about it). Windows was thinking this meant something was wrong and popping up an error over it which was hidden.

From reading the instructions here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/error-message-the-computer-restarted-unexpectedly/b770f14d-e345-e011-90b6-1cc1de79d2e2

I mounted the wim, edited the registry location at HKLocal machine/SYSTEM/SETUP/STATUS/ChildCompletion and changed childcompletion from 0 to 3 and put the wim back together. Imaged it again and it worked a treat.